# How to get current timestamp of firebase server in milliseconds?

Tags: android, firebase, timestamp, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to get firebase current timestamp, not able to find a way to get that. I want to save child as shown in the image. And for that I've to get timestamp and get the date accordingly. Please help...

[image: here is the result I want to get]

Comment: do you mean you want to set server time as a key with that format (dd-mm-yyyy)?

Comment: @wilik. Yes, exactly

Comment: Just a heads up , Firebase behavior for timestamps in Firestore has changed in the most recent version of Firestore 5.4.1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set the server time by using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` which is a `Map<String, String>` type with `{".sv" : "timestamp"}` pair. When it's sent to the firebase database, it will be converted to a Long [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) like this `1469554720`.

So the problem is, you can't set this as a key directly. The best approach is to put the timestamp inside your object and use `DatabaseReference.push()` to get the guaranteed unique key.

For example

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String key = ref.push().getKey(); // this will create a new unique key
Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("name", "shesh");
value.put("address", "lucknow");
value.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child(key).setValue(value);
```

If you want to save it with that format (dd-mm-yyyy), there's a hack but this is not recommended. You need to save it first (ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) to another temporary node, and then retrieve the timestamp before convert it into that format using `Date` class.

Comment: thank you very much..I tried this and its working fine. I can do this way too. But again is it possible to use this ServerValue.TIMESTAMP as a key?

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's possible but there will be two API call, set the TIMESTAMP value first and then get the last key by using `Query.limitToLast(1);`, this is not recommended because there is a probability that two users inserted two TIMESTAMPs at the same time so you can't get the correct key. BTW, please mark my answer as accepted if you think so. :)

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you can use cloud functions, and get the timestamp via an HTTP request.
The function is very simple.

```
exports.getTimeStamp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)=>{
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ timestamp: Date.now() }));
});
```

Comment: Technically that will get the timestamp of the node js server, which theoretically could be different than the server Firebase or Firestore Database is on.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for rising up the question
well, it's a unix time stamp which is the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970). so, technically, it does not change no matter where you are located on the globe, that's why it's widely used in computer systems nowadays.

Comment: Google servers will be set correctly, but another server could have the wrong time, no matter if the timestamp is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

On Android I did it this way

index.js / serverside

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
exports.stamp = functions.https.onCall(() => {
       var d = new Date();
       console.log('TimeStamp_now : '+d.getTime());
       return { timeStamp: d.getTime() };          
   });
```

someclass.kt / clientside

```
lateinit var functions: FirebaseFunctions
var ret :Long = 0

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()


val returnFC = functions.getHttpsCallable("stamp").call()
    returnFC.continueWith { task ->
    val resultFC = task.result?.data as Map<String, Any>
        resultFC["timeStamp"] as Long
    ret = "${resultFC["timeStamp"]}".toLong()
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.timeInMillis = "$ret".toLong()
    var date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString()
    Log.d("current date:", date)
    Log.d("timeStamp_from_function :", "$ret")
    resultFC
}
    returnFC.addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d("OnSuccessListener :", "success")
}    
    returnFC.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d("OnFailureListener:", "failure")
}
```

I got the return and arrived at: [TimestampConvert](https://www.timestampconvert.com/) look great

Answer (score 1):

in my experience(in TS and React )....

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; //v9

export const getNowTimeStamp = () =>{
  return firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
}
```

---

and after importing the method

```
import { getNowTimeStamp } from '..path/to/firebase.utils';
console.log( getNowTimeStamp().toMillis()  );
```

> o/p:1631264447901