# How to save Timestamp in Firebase in Appsmith app or using JSON?

Tags: json, firebase, date, timestamp, appsmith

I am trying to save the date/time in Firebase in timestamp format. I have referred answers from below posts.

[How to get current timestamp of firebase server in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593245/how-to-get-current-timestamp-of-firebase-server-in-milliseconds)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/n32ys2/how_can_i_save_the_values_in_the_datepicker_as/

I have tried saving data by adding different date formats in Body but it is ultimately getting added as a string or number depending upon string or timestamp.

Does anyone have idea how to send the date to Firestore using JSON or anything using which i can directly add it to Appsmith app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now Appsmith supports adding a server timestamp to any field in Firestore. Server timestamp is the timestamp provided by the Firestore server when that particular query was executed.

e.g. if there is entry like

```
{
    id : {name: foo, lastUpdated: ts}
}
```

then the `lastUpdated` field could be updated with the last update timestamp via setting the `Timestamp Value Path` to  `["id.lastUpdated"]`

Please checkout the video here and comment by user tazmaniax to understand more: https://github.com/appsmithorg/appsmith/pull/3693

Reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()

Appsmith's documentation for this is under progress and will be available on the Appsmith documentation site soon. Apologies for not putting it over there sooner.

For any other query or help please join Appsmith's [discord channel](https://discord.com/invite/rBTTVJp)

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that there is an error with the Firestore and Appsmith connector.

I have tried different combinations and if you do not send a string, int or bool in the json request, errors are generated.

However Appsmith added an additional field for handling timestamp (now)

[image]