# Writing the current Date and time to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

using this code with on button click listener

```
users.child(user.getUid()).child("Date").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

but i dont want it to be a TIMESTAMP like  1548105297646

Expected results:

**From  1548105297646  to  19/1/2019 19:33:40**

please check my Firebase database with expected results

[image: Firebase database]

Is there a code instead of (ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't directly write the server time to firebase in DateTime format.

You have one of two options:

1 - Write server time as timestamp, then when you read it when you want to use it do the conversion(that's what I do)

2 - If IT REALLY NEEDS TO BE STORED IN DateTime format, then you can write the server time stamp, read it, convert it, write it as DateTime.

Comment: but how i can convert it to normal when im trying to retrieve it on phone??

Comment: Google java convert timestamp to date

Comment: this child "date" is renewable and i want to retrieve it on my phone..its not logic to search for a converter everytime to see the normal date!!

Comment: Search for a code on how to convert it, and add the code to the app to display it

Comment: i have searched for the code ,thats why im posting this question now

Comment: Check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929929/convert-timestamp-into-current-date-in-android

Comment: Thanks , Mocas ..but these codes always show errors when i put it instead of my code :(

Comment: Then you need to resolve this question, and raise another question with your issue, add code and error message

Answer (score 1):

In Realtime Database, if you time ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, you will always write a number measured in milliseconds since the unix epoch.  You can't change this behavior.

If you want to write a string to the database, then compose the string yourself and write that value.  But I will suggest that writing the number is a much better option, since they're easier to search and sort in the database.  You should probably format that date value on the client instead.  Java (and Android in particular) have great date and time formatting libraries you can use.

Comment: but its not logic to write it normal date everytime :(

Comment: I don't know what that means.