# convert timestamp into current hour and minute in android

Tags: android, api, time, openweathermap

how to convert sunrise and sunset unix timestrap to current hour and minute by openweathermap api in android studio? Thankyou

```
"sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 9383,
        "country": "ID",
        "sunrise": 1580424864,
        "sunset": 1580469435
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamp in milliseconds to string formatted time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/convert-timestamp-in-milliseconds-to-string-formatted-time-in-java)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930056/1712446

Answer (score 4):

first get timestemp and convert by this method

```
  private void convertDate(long time) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
  cal.setTimeInMillis(time * 1000);
  int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   }
```